# How is an HTML5 game sold?

Tags: html5, legal, publishing

*(I know this site doesn't give legal advice, but what I'm dealing here with isn't anything serious at all. Also, I apologize to JP for being annoying over this.)*

Someone found a game I made on the Internet, and expressed interest in buying it. We agreed upon a price, and, in the meantime, I removed the game's source from the Internet, just to be sure.

Now, I'm wondering what to do next.

These are the terms:

- He gets the game's source code, and only that, without the graphics (which weren't made by me).
- He gets the right to develop and sell the game.
- I get to keep the ownership of the original game, meaning that I can use it in my portfolio when applying for jobs, for example.
- The game gets to stay on its original site.

But I am not sure how can I legally realize this. Which license can I use?

Comment: You basically need to copyright the software and then sell the copyrights for the software(not the assets) to the person interested in buying your game.

Comment: But when I sell the copyright, do I still legally own the game? Also, which license should I use to copyright it? Because if I used MIT, it would be illegal to charge for it!

Comment: The type of license depends on the buyer and what he intends to do with the software later on. I think the license is not part of the actual copyright, the license describes what other people are allowed to do with the software. The copyright is a legal concept that gives the creator or the buyer in this case exclusive rights. The copyrights grant you the right to determine the license.

Comment: @Bane You can sell MIT licensed code (I'm not sure if you have to do some virtual one character change, but probably not). Keep in mind a license is limiting a product user (the one who buys) not maker (the one who sells)

Comment: You can still own your game if it is agreed in the contract that you'll have license to distribute your game and he has copyrights over the software.

Comment: I doubt that we will be signing a contract. I think the easiest solution is this: I license the game under MIT, sell it to him, he starts working on it and attributes me, while licensing his work under a proprietary license.

Comment: MIT is an opensource license, it permits using your code in commercial projects without your permission.

Comment: So the general idea is that I'm actually selling that permission, right? (Also, I thought MIT was the do-what-you-want license, and that it just implied the attribution of the author.)

Comment: Generally, code isn't considered art (depending on presidence) so you're really just selling the code as-is (as the game art isn't included). The game idea can't be copyrighted anyway (anyone could just make a clone of your game) so basically your just selling the work as-is including the name of the game.
In copyright (at least in France) you don't sell *your* rights, you only give them the right to copy/distribute.
In any case, make a contract, however small it is stipulating clearly the rights you wish to keep on the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter which license is used. What you pass to the buyer is the copyrights. He can then choose any license.

When you make the agreement, note that you are transferring copyrights over the engine(code) and not the game assets. Also note, that you retain license over the game in it's original form, to distribute it and showcase it for any purpose without infringing on the copyrights of the game's engine(code). You will keep the code secure to protect the interests of the buyer in this contract.

So to keep things short and sweet:

Make a contract that states the following:

1. The buyer receives full copyrights on the game engine(code) and receives no rights over the game assets.
2. The seller retains the license to distribute the game in it's original form without modifying and/or reselling the engine(code).

This is no replacement for legal advice. In this case where you choose to avoid professional legal advice it may suffice to draft a contract like this yourself. That is your responsibility.

Comment: It's definitely not worth any lawyer fees, and I'm not a US citizen, but what do you mean by "sufficient guaranty"?

Comment: Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_registration#Is_registration_required.3F if your country's not there, then you're not obliged to register copyrights.

Comment: My country is not on the list, so that means that I hold the copyright implicitly, right?

Comment: Since there is not a lot of money involved, I suppose you could draft a contract that states you are passing the copyrights in return for said payment and you retain copyrights on your game in it's current form. The wording may vary, I would not worry about it too much if the amounts of money involved in this deal are not sufficient to warrant hiring a lawyer than it would be based on something more valuable, honour between you two. Most legal battles are won by spending large sums of money. So as long as both of you are protected from other parties by copyrights it does not matter much.

Comment: I mean it does not matter if the purchase agreement will hold in court cause it is very unlikely it will get there.

Comment: @Bane "Copyright is itself an automatic international right, governed by international conventions". Yes, you are correct

Comment: Isn't signing a contract on the Internet worthless? Couldn't any party just claim that "this sketch on that image was not made by me"?

Comment: Yeah, I supposed you were going to meet and sign in person. Generally when I sign a contract I do it in person with two witnesses and sign every page in the contract. I never signed a contract online.

Comment: I suggest you refrain from this if possible:
http://public.findlaw.com/abaflg/flg-10-1-8.html
Is there any way you could sign in person? You need to copies of the contract signed by both parties.

Comment: Let's not go too far, Arthur :) I think as not big money are involved, you're just fine with a gentleman agreement. You have copyrights, Bane. Your client sends you money, you send him source codes. You exchange e-mails and that's some evidence as well. I believe that's enough in this case.

Comment: -1, did not specifically address any points in the original question.

Comment: @Bane That's what digital signatures are for. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/how-to-achieve-non-repudiation

Comment: @JustinSkiles - I modified the answer to address these points.

Comment: ..."When you make the agreement, note that you are transferring copyrights over the engine(code) and not the game assets."  Are you sure about that?  Does it always work that way, every time?  I've never sold an HTML5 game, but that's not at all how it works elsewhere in the industry.

Comment: @TrevorPowell 1. This is specific to his questions. He wants to retain rights to distribute the game and transfer rights over the source(engine). 2. Please share your experience, you may know something we don't and I'd be happy to learn. 3.I basically offered an answer that meets his description: not enough money is involved to make it worth hiring a lawyer. In this specific case I believe what both parties want is an agreement with an understanding that will give them a peace of mind.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that part of the question.  :)

Comment: @wolfdawn Old answer, but "It does not matter which license is used. What you pass to the buyer is the copyrights." there might be some jurisdictions where that's a thing, but in many jurisdictions there's not such thing as transferring copyright. Copyright in those jurisdictions is the same as authorship. You would need to provide a license in that case (if you wanted to equivalent to signing over copyright you'd basically have to grant them a license to do whatever they want with it along with signing a contract saying you'll only use it with their permission).

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking at is a standard Game Distribution Agreement. The buyer gets to modify properties of your game and commercialize them, but you maintain all intellectual property rights (covering the game's original source code and assets ).

Just like any other agreement, make sure you're signing it with someone who has reputation. Avoid at all costs people you don't previously know, or do not belong to a certain gaming community. A buyer who is a legitimate game company would be ideal, because they'll understand the distribution agreement.